# $.each in jQuery fails to show html

Tags: jquery

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I want to get the values from obj printed in the table below. `obj` contains `listOfData` and there is a field `someValue`. Example below

```
JSON - {"listOfData":[{"id":"XX","someValue":"James Bond"}]} 

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON)
$.each(obj.listOfData, function (index, data) {   
   "<tr>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +
           index
       "</td>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" + 
           data.someValue
       "</td>" + 
    "</tr>" +
}
```

The output I get in JSP is `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're re-parsing an already JSON object into JSON - just use it directly.

Second, your concatenation is invalid, you forgot some plusses there.

Third, you didn't do anything with the string. You need to do something with it.

```
JSON = {
    "listOfData": [{
        "id": "XX",
        "someValue": "James Bond"
    }]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(JSON.listOfData, function (index, data) {  
      $('body').append(
       "<tr>" +
           "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +
               index +
           "</td>" +
           "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" + 
               data.someValue +
           "</td>" + 
        "</tr>");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPmqV/)

Comment: That's not at all what he was telling you oO

Comment: His second comment is resolved. Third comment, I was already doing and his first comment could not be done because I am getting JSON as a String. Have to parse otherwise gets an error.

Answer (score 3):

The `jQuery.parseJSON` function takes a string whereas from what you have shown the JSON variable is already a javascript object that you could directly work with:

```
var value = '';
$.each(JSON.listOfData, function (index, data) {   
   value += "<tr>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +
           index
       "</td>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" + 
           data.someValue
       "</td>" + 
    "</tr>";
});
// do something with the value you constructed here
```

That parsing would have been necessary if your `JSON` variable looked like this:

```
var JSON = "{\"listOfData\":[{\"id\":\"XX\",\"someValue\":\"James Bond\"}]}";
```

I guess the reason why the JSON variable is already a javascript object is because you used it as parameter to the success callback of an AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function(JSON) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The reason why you don't need to parse it is because you either specified `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` request or the server simply set the `Content-Type` response header to `application/json` and jQuery was able to infer and automatically parse the response to the server to the corresponding javascript object that got passed to the success callback.

Comment: I get a string back which I load in jQuery.parseJSON. So you saying I should have not loaded the String to parse in a JSON object? hmmmm good point.. Let me try it.

Comment: Are you sure that it is a string? Try directly using it as shown in my example. Also notice how in my answer I have replaced the contents of the $.each function with real javascript. In your example you just had some meaningless string concatenations which is invalid javascript. You need to assign those string concatenations to a variable.

Comment: I tried without converting to JSON and it failed and your guess is right that its a String what I get. BTW I was doing something with the HTML but we all missed one thing.... (+) a plus sign after index and data.someValue. I know its lame but that was the problem. :( After adding the plus sign it worked. Voted up your response.

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating through the collection and making html but not using it.

```
var myHtml = '';

$.each(obj.listOfData, function (index, data) {   
  myHtml += "<tr>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +
           index +
       "</td>" + 
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" + 
           data.someValue
       "</td>" + 
    "</tr>" +
}

$('#tableId').append(myHtml);
```

Comment: Please read my last comment for @Darin Dimitrov. Voting up your response... but I think we missed (+) sign after index and data.someValue.